# Xamarin font with not default size can't be vertically centered

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to vertically center label in grid cell, but text shifts down.
Green text - Default size.
Red text - Medium size.
White text - Large size.

I tried YAlign="Center" and VerticalTextAlignment="Center". No result.
My code for white label:

```
<Label    
HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
HorizontalOptions="End"
XAlign="Center"
VerticalOptions="Center"
Text="35,34" 
FontSize="Large" 
FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}" 
TextColor="#FFFFFF"
Grid.Row="1" 
Grid.Column="2"
/>
```

My code for grid:

```
<Grid Padding="15,7,15,10" RowSpacing="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hf8l.png)

Comment: you can try VerticalTextAlign property as center.

Comment: Already tried. No result.

Comment: please share the whole grid (columns and rows)

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk shared